# Java programming Input:Today is Sunday Output:Sunday is today

Tags: java

String str="Today is Sunday"

And the output should be "Sunday is Today"

I need a code for this program in **Java**.

Is there any other method to do it...

Comment: split method will split the string and return all splitted string as array

Comment: Is this `Java` or `Javascript`?

Comment: but how....can u provide me the code....and bty the input is String

Comment: then why question is tagged with javascript category

Comment: I have the feeling you should read up some basic guides on Java. As people pointed out, JavaScript is different from Java. Please don't tag it with both.

Comment: And where are the semi-colons?

Comment: @mbs Fixed the semicolons.

Answer (score 3):

This feels like a question for a university assignment, but in essence, you need to split the array then reverse it.

```
 var elems = inStr.split(' ');
 elems.reverse();
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

For the record, JavaScript and Java are different languages, and I've written JavaScript.

EDIT: In Java, it's something like this:

```
 String inStr = "today is thursday";
 String[] elems = inStr.split("\ ");
```

You can then just loop backwards over the array.

Comment: Added, but my Java isn't overly strong so someone can probably improve it.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you can use `push()` method to store value into array, It adds the new item into end of the array.

```
var arr = [];

arr.push('Today')
arr.push('is')
arr.push('sunday')
```